# Android : difference in OBTAINING_IP_ADDR WiFi supplicant state

Tags: android

In the Android App, am trying to listen for WiFi on/off state changes. I have registered for 
SUPPLICANT_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION

When WiFi is turned on, the state changes from
Scanning
to
Connecting
to
Authenticating
to 
OBTAINING_IP_ADDR

Then it stays at OBTAINING_IP_ADDR. But when not connected to WiFi also, the supplicant state says OBTAINING_IP_ADDR. How do we differentiate between the OBTAINING_IP_ADDR when WiFi is being connected to, and the OBTAINING_IP_ADDR when the WiFi is off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are interested in wifi state change not supplicant state change. Supplicant State is more refined.

Register for WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION and check EXTRA_WIFI_STATE extra value attached with intent as getIntExtra(String, int). It will tell you like WIFI_STATE_DISABLED, DISABLING, ENABLED, ENABLING etc.